# Blender automatically closes when i try to save a render as a png image

Tags: rendering, error

My blender crashes when i try to save a blender render as a png file
I normally click on render as image and it renders and when it finishes rendering i click image and save as png then i go to my save location and click save but when i click save blender crashes and doesnt save my file...If you need more information just comment on it and also i got images but i am new to stack exchange and i dont know how to add..Any help would be appreciated thanks alot..

Comment: try saving it as a copy?

Comment: ok i will try that..

Comment: should i save the render as the copy or the whole blend file?

Comment: That didn’t work..